# Multiple celery workers pointing to different brokers on same Django project

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, messagebroker

I want to run 2 celery workers on same Django project. This can easily be done using command line tool. 
But I want both the workers to have separate rabbitmq broker running on 2 separate hosts.

Out of the 2 brokers one broker is local and resides on the same host.
The other broker is a central server which pushes periodic messages to a queue.
My question is how can I have such kind of configuration to be able to spawn 2 different workers, both pointing to 2 different brokers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Aren't two separate queues on the same broker enough?

Comment: @jsbeckr No it's not enough because I have a central server which pushes messages to a fanout exchange. There are multiple services (separate django applications hosted on different servers) which binds to this exchange using it's own queue. That is why I need a 2nd broker which points to this central rabbitmq broker. I already have a configuration where each services has it's own rabbitmq broker and celery worker and now I want another worker in each services that should point to central rabbitmq broker